# No write access to $HOME in tmux after logout and login

Tags: kerberos, tmux, openafs

I am not able to write to files in $HOME (on an Andrew File System) in tmux after logging out and logging in again.

```
(.lobster)[earth] ~/lobster >touch test
touch: setting times of `test': Permission denied
```

My problem seems similar to the one described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198959/not-permitted-to-access-my-files-on-home-in-tmux-after-log-out-and-log-in) except that for me, the permissions look fine:

```
(.lobster)[earth] ~/lobster >ls -ld
drwxr--r-- 7 awoodard campus 2048 Mar 28 15:55 .
```

I've tried checking `KRB5CCNAME` outside of tmux and updating it to the same value inside of tmux, to no avail.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFS file system implementations such as [OpenAFS](http://www.openafs.org/) and [AuriStorFS](https://www.auristor.com/filesystem/) use AFS tokens for authentication not Kerberos tickets.  AFS tokens can be obtained using Kerberos via the `aklog` command.  When executed without parameters `aklog` will use the Kerberos ticket granting ticket stored in the current Kerberos credential cache to acquire an AFS token for the default workstation cell.  The workstation cell can be determined using the `fs wscell` command.

```
host# fs wscell
This workstation belongs to cell 'auristor.com'
```

To determine if you have an AFS token for a cell use the 'tokens' command.

```
host# tokens

Tokens held by the Cache Manager:

Rxgk Tokens for auristor.com [Expires Apr 03 12:43]
User's (AFS ID 103) rxkad tokens for auristor.com [Expires Apr 03 12:43]
```

If you wish to obtain AFS tokens for a cell other than the workstation cell

```
host# aklog grand.central.org
```

Finally, you can obtain debugging output from `aklog` with the `-d` paramenter.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm marking this answer as the solution because it explained the missing pieces for me. For anyone arriving here with the same problem, the final step I needed was to run `kinit` and then `aklog`.